# ReactJS How to prevent multiple API calls occurring in componentDidMount function

Tags: reactjs

I have the following axios request given inside `componentDidMount` function and when I inspect the network I found API called 6 times. What will be the reason for this much calls triggered and is there any other function or solutions to solve this?

```
componentDidMount(){
     axios.get(this.state.url+'tables', { headers: { 'authorization': token } })
     .then(response => { 
         const regions = response.data.data.regions,
                state = response.data.data.state,
                directory = response.data.data.directory,

         this.setState({ regions,state,directory });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log('error ' + error);
      });

}
```

Comment: Can you should your component and also how you use that component and whereall

Comment: @Hareesh `componentDidMount ` is called only once in component mounting process.API called multiple times means component is unamounted and mounted  several times.

Comment: where you are using this component, Please share code

Answer (score 2):

It should be because there will be 6 instances of this component rendered in your client.  Maybe you are including this component inside say an array.map

Comment: It's either this or you are unmounting and remounting the component.

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix, I recommend reading the article within the lower link, but for local testing, remove `React.StrictMode` (these two lines) from `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode> //<--- REMOVE
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>, //<--- REMOVE
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Credits to:

- https://andreasheissenberger.medium.com/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625